# WPF program won't load after code change

Tags: c#, arrays, wpf

Application was working fine until I added code for two arrays. I have some class level strings:

```
string cFileName = "customer.txt";
string[] cName = new string[0];
string[] cPhone = new string[0];
```

And I've added this to the `Window_Loaded` event:

```
private void Window_Loaded_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //read file on start
    //ReadFile();
    int counter = 0;
    string line;
    StreamReader custSR = new StreamReader(cFileName);
    line = custSR.ReadLine();

    while (custSR.Peek() != -1)
    {
        Array.Resize(ref cPhone, cPhone.Length + 1);
        Array.Resize(ref cName, cName.Length + 1);

        cPhone[cPhone.Length - 1] = line;
        cName[cName.Length - 1] = line;
        counter++;

        //phoneComboBox.Items.Add(cPhone[cPhone.Length - 1]);
     }
     custSR.Close();

     for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++)
     {
         phoneComboBox.Items.Add(cPhone[i]);
     }
     //focus when program starts
     phoneComboBox.Focus();
}
```

The reason I have `//ReadFile()` is because I tried to have it as a separate method and call to the `Window_Loaded` event. I also tried ouputting to the combo box from within the loop. I have not had this happen before and can't figure out what I've done.

Comment: put a try catch around and see if your exceptions are silent

Comment: @GabrielGM how can a try catch help if it won't load? I tried, but still won't load

Comment: Did you check `eventvwr` for any errors specific to this app? Also, did you try running the app under debugger?

Comment: I added `line = custSR.ReadLine();` and it loads, now I have the problem where everything went into a single array!

Comment: @sthotakura no, I did not, will remember that for the future.

Comment: This is just messed up.  It was loading but was in an infinite loop.  Did you you try debug?  Why use Array.Resize for every line.  Use a List.

Comment: @Paparazzi A list works far easier, but I had to read the data to two arrays, so this is what I came up with

Comment: Had too?  And you had to re-size in a loop?

Comment: @Paparazzi it was for an assignment. I don't ask for people to do it for me, just point out the issues so I can learn. And I resized the array because that's what I figured out to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not reading the next line to break the loop. I'm marking this as my answer as it fixed the issue and incase anyone happens to stumble across this issue in the future.

```
while (custSR.Peek() != -1)
{
    Array.Resize(ref cPhone, cPhone.Length + 1);
    Array.Resize(ref cName, cName.Length + 1);

    cPhone[cPhone.Length - 1] = line;
    cName[cName.Length - 1] = line;
    counter++;

    line = custSR.ReadLine();  //needed this to read next line
 }
```